# Extract one value from a column containing multiple delimited values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, tokenize

How can I get the value from the sixth field in the following column?  I am trying to get the 333 field:

```
ORGPATHTXT
2123/2322/12323/111/222/333/3822
```

I believe I have to use `select substring`, but am unsure how to format the query

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Does that mean Microsoft's SQL Server?  If so, which version?

Comment: Yes, MS SQL Server v10.50.4000

Comment: Note that this violates normalization; each "field" should be stored in a separate row of a new table with a foreign key to the original row.

Comment: @DourHighArch Some hierarchical algorithms use this pattern to store organisation hierarchies.

Answer (score 2):

> **Assuming SQL Server**

The easiest way I can think of is create a Split function that splits based on '/' and you extract the sixth item like below

```
declare @text varchar(50) = '2123/2322/12323/111/222/333/3822'

select txt_value from fn_ParseText2Table(@text, '/') t where t.Position = 6
```

I used the function in [this url](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str). [**See it worked at SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6a04/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this - for a string `variable`  or wrap into a `function` to use with a select query ([Sql-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8370))

```
Declare @s varchar(50)='2123/2322/12323/111/222/333/3822'

Select @s = right(@s,len(@s)- case charindex('/',@s,1) when 0 then len(@s) 
                              else charindex('/',@s,1) end)
From ( values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) As t(num)

Select case when charindex('/',@s,1)>0 then left(@s,charindex('/',@s,1)-1) 
            else @s end

--Results
333
```

Comment: @TimLehner: This works with a string variable only. Otherwise select list has to put in a cursor/loop and fill the results into a temp table using this method.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to offer a solution that uses `CROSS APPLY` to split up any delimited string in MSSQL and `ROW_NUMBER()` to return the 6th element.  This assumes you have a table with ORGPATHTXT as a field (it can easily be converted to work without the table though):

```
SELECT ORGPATHTXT
FROM (
  SELECT 
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ORGPATHTXT,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN
  FROM  
    (SELECT ID, CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(ORGPATHTXT, '/', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  MyTable
  ) AS A 
  CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
  ) t 
WHERE t.RN = 6;
```

Here is some sample [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba08d/8) to go along with it.

Good luck.

Comment: When I try to use this I get a message saying illegal name character

Comment: That's an XML Parser error I believe -- you sure the data is always in the above format?  Have you tried my SQL Fiddle?

Comment: The data can be alpha or numeric and is variable in length

Comment: My guess is you have a < or > in your data which is conflicting with the XML ?

Comment: Looks like you could REPLACE those brackets like this: REPLACE(ORGPATHTXT,'<','&lt;')?  -- Updated Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c2dd/1

Answer (score 1):

For sql, you can use

```
declare @string varchar(65) = '2123/2322/12323/111/222/333/3822'

select substring(string,25,27) from table_name
```

Comment: Values in this field are variable, so I doubt this would work

Comment: Why does `sql` associate with SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, then you can use:

```
select substring_index(orgpathtxt, '/', 6)
```

Let me just say that it is less convenient in most other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use option with dynamic management function [sys.dm_fts_parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc280463%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(50) = '2123/2322/12323/111/222/333/3822' 

SELECT display_term
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"'+ @s + '"', 1033, NULL, 0) 
WHERE display_term NOT LIKE 'nn%' AND occurrence = 6
```